# MongoDB collection index with complex query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation, mongodb-atlas

I have refined an aggregation query over and over, the query itself is returning exactly the correct information however I am receiving lots of Query targeting alerts as  Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000.

I am guessing my collection index's are not suitable.

Any help with the below aggregation pipeline and suitable index's to create would be greatly appreciated!

The below query checks and returns bookings where the start date for any days within a bookings collection fall between the 2 dates.

```
// example booking document
{
  status: 1,
  client: ObjectId,
  customer: ObjectId,
  days: [{ start: date }, { startL date }]
}
```

status and client on the below aggregation are optional, this same query is also often executed without those.

```
.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          "status": 1,
          "client": "ObjectId"
          "customer": "ObjectId",
          "days": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "start": {
                "$gte": "2023-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "$lte": "2023-02-28T23:59:59.999Z"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "createdAt": 1
        }
      }
]);
```

I have tried adding a variety of indexes, examining my query using `cursor.explain()` but all indexes or amends to the above query are not fixing the issue.

Below is a link to the explain output:
https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/y229660e2

Comment: Please edit your question to include or link to the explain output. The filters on `client` and `customer` seem odd at a glance, why does one include the `$oid` wrapper and the other does not? And for what it's worth, this could be done with a `find()` and doesn't need a full aggregation

Comment: Note that the Scanned Objects / Returned metric is not based on a single query, it is the total number of objects scanned since the node was last started divided by the total number returned since the last start.  Do the logs or explain indicate that this query is the problem?

Comment: @user20042973 the $oid wrapper was a copy and paste error, I have amended that, there are also other things going on that mean an aggregate query is required, they are just not relevant to my question so I have emitted them.

Comment: @Joe the logs do indicate that this query is the problem, I have been examining the query profiler which highlights the specific queries causing the various alerts and the above query is responsble

Comment: @user20042973 I have added a link to the explain output too, it's the first time I have used this method to find out more info so not too sure what I am looking for

Comment: That explain output shows it ran in less than a millisecond and examined 0 documents to return 0